# Values from external .txt file different when imported into console

Tags: java, arrays, file, filereader

I'm bringing in values from a .txt file and putting them into an array, but the numbers that end up stored in the array are different than whats in the file and I don't understand why or how I can fix it.

The text file is laid out with these values

```
2
20.0
10.0
100
```

The method that imports the values into the file is:

```
//variables global to the class
    public static int level; 
    public static int hp; 
    public static double vigor; 
    public static double intelligence; 

public static void checkSaveState() throws IOException 
    {
        //this method checks the save file for data
        try
        {
            double[] savedGa = new double[4];
            BufferedReader saveFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("HRHeroSaveGame.txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                savedGa[i] = saveFile.read();
            }
            level = (int) savedGa[0];
            vigor = savedGa[1];
            intelligence = savedGa[2];
            hp = (int) savedGa[3];

            System.out.println("Level: " + level + " Vigor: " + vigor + " Intelligence: " + intelligence + " HP: " + hp);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, a save file couldn't be found for you.");
        }

    }
```

The output always ends up like this:

```
Level: 50 Vigor: 13.0 Intelligence: 10.0 HP: 50
```

Just in case this is relevant, this is the method that created the file.

```
public static void saveGame() throws IOException
{
    PrintWriter saveFile = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter("HRHeroSaveGame.txt"));
    saveFile.println(level);
    saveFile.println(vigor);
    saveFile.println(intelligence);
    saveFile.println(hp);
    saveFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a sanity check? i.e. writing the text file manually and trying to read it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read()` reads a single char. This explains your results: `'2'` = 50, `'\r'` = 13, `'\n'` = 10

You have to read each line as `String` and parse it to get doubles:

```
savedGa[i] = Double.parseDouble(saveFile.readLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

The read() method of BufferReader reads an integer representation of a char, not a complete line cast to double or int.

To fix this just change your for-loop to this

```
try
        {
            double[] savedGa = new double[4];
            BufferedReader saveFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/test.txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                savedGa[i] = Double.parseDouble(saveFile.readLine());
            }
            level = (int) savedGa[0];
            vigor = savedGa[1];
            intelligence = savedGa[2];
            hp = (int) savedGa[3];

            System.out.println("Level: " + level + " Vigor: " + vigor + " Intelligence: " + intelligence + " HP: " + hp);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, a save file couldn't be found for you.");
        }
```

This reads the whole line as a String and then parses it to double.